# How can I send a Wake-On-LAN packet to my PC on another network

Tags: windows, wake-on-lan

I have been using WakeMeOnLan to power on my PC from my laptop, and have heard it is possible to send a magic packet to a modem on another network and have it forwarded to the target device. I believe I have set up forwarding correctly, but I am unsure how to actually send the packet to the modem. WakeMeOnLAN only shows the devices on my local network, does it support sending packets to a modem on another network?

Comment: You could probably use TeamViewer https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/turn-on-computer-from-across-the-house-with-wake-on-lan if you connect your devices through a TeamViewer account. You can then open the program and click the Wake Up button to wake up any sleeping PC connected to your account. Other remote access tools may also support Wake-on-LAN, so check with your program of choice to see what settings you need to enable for it to work. Wake-on-WAN is also explained if you scroll down a bit.